# Android Studio: My project view looks different

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been working on a project for a few weeks in Android Studio. All of a sudden when I opened it today, the project structure is all messed up.

Usually, it looks something like this: 
[A standard Project Structure](http://unhackathon.org/springboard-projects/img/filestructure.png).

However, upon opening,  My Project Structure looks like this:
[My Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmQLf.jpg).

Any help on reformatting my project structure would be great. I really can't navigate it and find my Layout XML's etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have selected "Project" rather than "Android"

Just select "Android" above the application name, and you are good to go.

[image]

Comment: Ah, now don't I look like a fool :| Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is messed up. You are just in a different view i.e. `project view`.

What you want to see is `Android View`.

**Change the view to "Android View"** by clicking on the dropdown at the top of the box.

Comment: Had I not been trying for an hour to resolve this problem, I'd feel less of a fool. Thank  you

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue, but after upgrading Android Studio from version 2.1 to 3.2.

I had to manually update my the gradle.buld (Module: app) file to the current 'buildToolsVersion' (which is not required after the upgrade).

I also updated 'compileSdkVersion' and 'targetSdkVersion' to the latest while I was at it.

I then proceeded with importing the project and was prompted to upgrade Gradle followed by correcting issues that lint complained about.

If anyone is interested in these details- ask and I will post.